# Is there a method to control VLC media player from a server, using PHP?

Tags: php, bash, vlc, lamp

I am trying to make a PHP app to control VLC on a Linux system (Raspberry Pi) running LAMP. When I access the Pi's IP address through my browser, a web interface is displayed. To simplify it for now, let us just say there is a specific pre-decided audio file that is to play when a button is clicked.

However I do not want it to play on the client's computer, but rather on the server itself (it is connected to a speaker).

After this, I do not know how to go about opening tracks on VLC. Could I possibly call a BASH script or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a command line interface for VLC. You can run vlc through system commands.

http://www.videolan.org/doc/vlc-user-guide/en/ch04.html

You can use 'exec' or other similar function to run these commands in php. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)